# Eliminate index.js from Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm looking for a solution to a pretty common webpack annoyance: within every folder in our app we need an index.js file that requires every other .js file within that folder and then exports them all so that webpack understands how we'd like to import them.

Is there any way to automate this via a custom Resolver / Loader?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need what now? I've used an index at the top-level of a library, but nothing in webpack requires you to have one for every directory. Why would you use that instead of relative paths in your import?

Comment: use a synchronous recursive `fs` search to require all `.js` files per directory

Comment: You don't "need" an index.js, and I imagine that pattern will result in more boilerplate in your bundle.  I would simply just bring in the modules you need directly in each import/require.